# Mysql Joint Two district column into one

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a data like this table name 'project'

```
| Place_name | project_name
==========================
| india      | PJT101
| india      | PJT201
| Singapore  | PJT100
| singapore  | PJT101
```

The result i need is the distinct values of two columns

```
Project_name_place
==================
india
singapore
PJT101
PJT201
PJT100
```

Comment: See UNION, and show us what you can come up with

Comment: You are unpivoting so UNION is appropriate.